# conemu - new console in new window?

Tags: conemu

Is there a possibility to open a new console in the command line in new window with ConEmu?

```
cmd -new_console -flag for new window
```

I am looking for this flag from the screenshot.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

There is no sense in using `-new_console` when you want to start new **instance** of ConEmu.

Just start ConEmu: https://conemu.github.io/en/ConEmuArgs.html

```
ConEmu64 -NoSingle -run cmd
```

Comment: if your task has spaces in its name , use this variation `./ConEmu64 -NoSingle -run {my CustomTaskName Here}`

Comment: The example in the answer is about exact command, not a task. If you want to run a **task** you always have to write it as `{Task}` to show your intention.